# How to change content while converting from xml to json in Spring?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, converters

I read an object as xml and produce json in spring everything is fine. However I want to change one of the variable. Let's say I read Object  Person

```
@XmlRootElement (name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class Person{
//a lot variable same when reading and response
private String nameSurname;
```

In above example I read xml `<nameSurname>JohnNash<nameSurname>`but I want to return `{"name":"John","surname":Nash}`

So what is the best approach to do it?

Should I use 2 different object and write a mapper function? (xmlPerson, jsonPerson)

Should I just change getter function to change content so that it will produce json as I want?

Should I use just 1 object and write custom json converter function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the XML and JSON should be similar because the general idea is to use RESTful services around the concept that whether you feed it XML or JSON format, it will deal with it in the same way - hence the need for convertors like Gson, Jackson, etc.

But, for some specific reason, if you want to map one XML element to two JSON attributes, the best way would be to deal with it would be to use a single object and write a json converter for it. This gives you the flexibility of putting the mapping code at one place which can be easily changes at a later point if need be.

Comment: I actually read xml from another service so this why i want to change variable names and maps to the different objects. Thank you for your answer.